# Order By Woocommerce Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Year (year-2) and Season (season) Product attribute set up on my product and I would like all my products pages to order by Year + Season.  It first, I tried only to order by year but I'm unable to:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
  if ( 'year_season' == $orderby_value ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'year-2';
    $args['meta_key'] = '_product_attributes';
    $args['order'] = 'desc';
  }
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
  $sortby['year_season'] = 'Sorty By: Year + Season';
  return $sortby;
}
```

Since _product_attributes is serialized is it even possible to sort by product attributes?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: I ended up only needing to order by Year so I never solved this.